# Element has greater px width than device viewport but still shows completely (mobile web app)

Tags: css, mobile

**Background:** I'm trying to make an application mobile friendly. But even though it's using bootstrap, lots of divs are super tiny when viewing the application with `iphone6` setting in chrome dev tools' `toggle device mode`.

Then I realized even though the device is 375px width,

[image]

The `<body>` element of the app is  980px width. And is fully showing on screen.

[image]

There is nowhere in the CSS thats forcing a width of 980px (as far as I can tell), so I'm quite confused.

I don't have much experience working on the front-end of applications so I'm afraid its a little over my head.

*Note: It is a Rails application and uses some AngularJS, if that can have any impact.*

Has anyone ran into this issue before, or has an idea how I might troubleshoot this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you add this code to you webpage? It tells the browser to control the page's dimensions and scaling.

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
```

It should be added inside the page's `<head>` tags.